# How to dynamically change JSON records?

Tags: c#, json, .net, jsonconvert

I have a JSON string in the following structure:

```
"{'Country':'USA','City':'New York','Population':'8554554','Area':'545887','jsonArgs':'{\"BuildingsTypes\":\"Offices\"}','keywords':['keyword1','keyword2']}"
```

What I need to do is to update *Area* and *BuildingsTypes* values.
I have tried to do the following:

```
string updatedJSON = String.Format("{'Country':'USA','City':'New York','Population':'8554554','Area':'{0}','jsonArgs':'{\"BuildingsTypes\":\"{1}\"}','keywords':['keyword1','keyword2']}", countryArea, buildingType);
```

However, I geting that structure is wrong, but if I use falowing as static it works.
I also have tried to create is as dynamic object as the following:

```
string[] stringKeywords = new string[] {"keyword1", "keyword2"};

var jsonArgs = new
                {
                    featureTypes = buildingType

                };
var layerDescription = new
                {
                    Country = "USA",
                    City = "New York",
                    Population = "8554554",
                    Area = countryArea,
                    jsonArgs = jsonArgs,
                    keywords = stringKeywords

                };
string stringJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(layerDescription);
```

By this I getting almost correct result:

```
"{'Country':'USA','City':'New York','Population':'8554554','Area':'545887','jsonArgs':{\"BuildingsTypes\":\"Offices\"},'keywords':['keyword1','keyword2']}"
```

What is missing here is single quotations around  `{\"BuildingsTypes\":\"Offices\"}` do to this the other application to which I'm sending the string is not accepting it.
How can I add dynamically the values or add the missing quotations?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the extra quotes around the jsonArgs value, then you need to convert the object to a string. The easiest way to do this is to make an additional call to the serializer.

```
var args = new { featureTypes = buildingType };
var jsonArgs = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the quotes like the rest just replace

`stringJSON.Replace("\"", "'");`